# Algorithm to find best strategy for placing blocks

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x

This game has a grid size 8x8. At the beginning of each round the player draws 3 blocks at random he must place on the grid. Placing a block is worth its area in points, and completing a row or column is worth 80 points, and that row or column is cleared from the board. The blocks do not move down after squares are cleared like in tetris.

If no more blocks can be placed, the game is over. The object of the game is to maximize your score.

Example:

[image: example]

[Example video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YVufA-WDi9U)

I am looking to create a program that will find the best possible strategy for placing blocks, when provided with the three blocks available to the user.

Currently, I have code to create a grid and a list of blocks.

```
class Piece():

    def __init__(self, shape):
        self.shape = shape


    def __str__(self):
        return self.render()


    def render(self):
        res = []

        for row in self.shape:
            res.append("".join(row)+"\n")

        return "".join(res)


pieces = [Piece([["x"]]),
          Piece([["x", "x"]]),
          Piece([["x", "x", "x"]]),
          Piece([["x", "x", "x", "x"]]),
          Piece([["x"],["x"]]),
          Piece([["x"], ["x"], ["x"]]),
          Piece([["x"], ["x"], ["x"], ["x"]]),
          Piece([["x", "x"], ["x", "x"]]),
          Piece([["x", "x"], ["x"]]),
          Piece([["x"], ["x", "x"]]),
          Piece([[" ", "x"], ["x", "x"]]),
          Piece([["x", "x"], [" ", "x"]]),
          Piece([["x", "x", "x"], ["x"], ["x"]]),
          Piece([["x", "x", "x"], [" ", " ", "x"], [" ", " ", "x"]]),
          Piece([[" ", " ", "x"], [" ", " ", "x"], ["x", "x", "x"]]),
          Piece([["x"], ["x"], ["x", "x", "x"]])
         ]
```

The code I used to create the grid is found here https://gist.github.com/Olical/2306105 (not mine)

My current approach would just be to search though the grid 1 place at a time for each piece to find somewhere to place it, although this doesn't seem very efficient.

What algorithm could/should I use in order to find this?

Comment: Usually, a bruteforce algorithm can generally work in small search space, as it seems in your case. Can you be more precise about the inefficiency you are facing?

Comment: Oh, ok. I just thought that brute force was generally not recommended, although I suppose an  8x8 grid is small enough that I could brute force it. I was just thinking there'd be a smarter way of finding the best place to put a block.

Comment: You need to include the relevant information from that video in the text of your question. Links in questions are permitted, but the question needs to be understandable without referring to the link. In particular, do you get a new piece each time you place a block, or do you need to place all 3 blocks before you get new pieces?

Comment: A common strategy for solving block puzzles like this is [backtracking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking). But whether or not you use backtracking you'll need to devise some way to evaluate block placements, apart from "does it fit here?". Eg you could calculate the bounding box of all the blocks currently on the board. A squarish bounding box is probably better. And a compact  bounding box with few holes is probably better. But those are just guesses. :)

Comment: You need to place all 3 block so before you get new blocks.

Comment: @NiVer this game is definitely too large to bruteforce. After every round you draw three new blocks at random, and rows and columns can be cleared, which makes the search tree very large.

Comment: @JosephBywater Do you have a list of all possible blocks and the frequencies they occur? That will be required to search the game tree

Comment: @PM2Ring Unfortunately this is too complex and dynamic for backtracking. We have random future blocks and lines being cleared off the board.

Comment: @Imran Fair enough. I suppose backtracking could still be used for just placing the current 3 blocks.

Comment: @Imran I'm sorry, I don't know the frequencies that the blocks appear. I assume that they are random. I thought that the game would provide three blocks that could definitely be placed if put in the correct order and in the correct places on the board although I once got a combination of three blocks that could not be placed and the game ended.

Comment: OK no problem. If you want to search / sample the game tree you can start with all possible blocks and assume they each have the same chance of appearing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a very simple approximation to the best strategy you can use a greedy strategy of trying to clear as many lines as possible in the current round.

You can also write a simple evaluation function to favor things like tight packing of blocks, leaving holes that future block shapes might fit nicely, etc.

However, I suspect this will be far from optimal because you may clear a line but leave a huge mess behind which will be hard to clear in future rounds.

If you want to find the optimal placement of the three blocks you will have to solve the entire [game tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_tree), since the block placements decides not only your score for the current round, but also how well you will do in future rounds.

Since the game tree is far to large to solve completely, you will have to find a good approximate solution. For a number of reasons, I think this problem is a good candidate for [Monte Carlo Tree Search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_tree_search), for example:

- The game tree is large with a high branching factor
- The game has a clear forward directionality
- Playing random moves will tend to score better starting from better board positions.
- MCTS does not require writing an evaluation function for non-terminal positions

The game tree will have two kinds of nodes: player nodes and chance nodes. Each player node represents one block placements on the board, and each chance node represents the three blocks you draw at random at the beginning of the round which the player has no control over.

The pseudocode for the MCTS algorithm for this game will be:

```
def MCTS(root, board, n_sims):
    for 1...n_sims:
        b = board.copy()
        cur_node = root
        while cur_node.vists >= expand_threshold:
            if cur_node is expanded:
                if cur_node is chance node:
                    cur_node = sample child uniformly at random
                else:
                    cur_node = child that maximizes UCT score
                b.update(cur_node) # update the board position with the block placement or the new three block draw
            else if b.game_over():
                break
            else:
                expand(cur_node, b) # add all child nodes to tree
        score = b.roll_out() # play random moves to the end of the game and return final score
        cur_node.backprop(score) # propagate score and visit back up tree
    return most visited child of root

root = new Node(parent=null, total_score=0, visits=0)
board = new Board(current position)
best_move = MCTS(root, board, 10000)
print(best_move)
```

You'll want to use `total_score/visits` in the UCT score (rather than wins/visits for two-player games), and you can propagate the score up the tree by storing total score and visits at each node and adding the score of the current simulation to the total score and by incrementing the visit count.